setting custom ringtone when in foreground working fine but in background not working
hi i am trying to implement custom ringtone when get notification in foreground working fine ringtone playing and stopping fine but when the app is in background the ringtone is ringing but Unable to stop it what i find is handleBackgroundMessage is creating new instance and in MyApp having diffrent instance of objects and
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  NotificationHandler().onSelectNotification(json.encode(message.data));
});

this method is called from Myapp so it has diffrent instance can anybody suggest what i am doing wrong here my code is below
   Future<void> handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
   if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
   } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    }
  final liveAstrologerController = Get.put(LiveAstrologerController());
 final walletController = Get.put(WalletController());
 final chatController = Get.put(ChatController);
  final callController = Get.put(CallController());
 final reportController = Get.put(ReportController());
 if (message.notification!.title == "For Live Streaming Chat") {
   Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then((value) async {
      await localNotifications.cancelAll();
    });
String sessionType = message.data["sessionType"];
if (sessionType == "start") {
  String? liveChatUserName2 = message.data['liveChatSUserName'];
  if (liveChatUserName2 != null) {
    liveAstrologerController.liveChatUserName = liveChatUserName2;
    liveAstrologerController.update();
  }
  String chatId = message.data["chatId"];
  liveAstrologerController.isUserJoinAsChat = true;
  liveAstrologerController.update();
  liveAstrologerController.chatId = chatId;
  int waitListId = int.parse(message.data["waitListId"].toString());
  String time = liveAstrologerController.waitList
      .where((element) => element.id == waitListId)
      .first
      .time;
     liveAstrologerController.endTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch +
       1000 * int.parse(time.toString());
       liveAstrologerController.update();
   } else {}
     } else if (message.notification!.title ==
        "For timer and session start for live") {
     liveAstrologerController.update();
  } else if (message.notification!.title == "Start simple chat timer") {
 } else {
try {
  if (message.data.isNotEmpty) {
    var messageData = json.decode((message.data['body']));

    if (messageData['notificationType'] != null) {
      if (messageData['notificationType'] == 7) {
        // get wallet api call
        await walletController.getAmountList();
      } else if (messageData['notificationType'] == 8) {
        chatController.startRingTone();
        //AlarmHandler.scheduleAlarm();
        chatController.chatList.clear();
        chatController.update();

        await chatController.getChatList(false);
        debugPrint('chat resp-> $messageData');
      } else if (messageData['notificationType'] == 2) {
        //in background
        callController.startRingTone();

        await callController.getCallList(false);
      } else if (messageData['notificationType'] == 9) {
        reportController.reportList.clear();
        reportController.update();
        await reportController.getReportList(false);
      } else if (messageData['notificationType'] == 12 ||
          messageData['notificationType'] == 11 ||
          messageData['notificationType'] == 10) {
        liveAstrologerController.isUserJoinWaitList = true;
        liveAstrologerController.update();
      }
    }
  }
} catch (e) {
  debugPrint("Exception in _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler else $e");
}
 }
}

and myapp is
 void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
 await GetStorage.init();
 await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();

 if (Platform.isAndroid) {
   await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
 } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
 }

 HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();

runApp(
   EasyLocalization(
     supportedLocales: const [
       Locale('en', 'US'),
     ],
     path: 'assets/translations',
    fallbackLocale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
    startLocale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
   child: const MyApp(),
 ),
 );
 }

 class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyApp({super.key});

    @override
    State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
   }

  class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
     dynamic analytics;
     final apiHelper = APIHelper();

    dynamic observer;
    final liveAstrologerController = Get.put(LiveAstrologerController());
    final walletController = Get.put(WalletController());
    final chatController = Get.put(ChatController());
    final callController = Get.put(CallController());
    final timerController = Get.put(TimerController());
    final reportController = Get.put(ReportController());
    final networkController = Get.put(NetworkController());

 @override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
     log('chat hascode MyApp ${chatController.hashCode}');
     log('call hascode MyApp ${callController.hashCode}');
    inthandlerbackgroudn();

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
  if (message.notification!.title == "For Live Streaming Chat") {
    String sessionType = message.data["sessionType"];
    if (sessionType == "start") {
      String? liveChatUserName2 = message.data['liveChatSUserName'];
      if (liveChatUserName2 != null) {
        liveAstrologerController.liveChatUserName = liveChatUserName2;
        liveAstrologerController.update();
      }
      String chatId = message.data["chatId"];
      liveAstrologerController.isUserJoinAsChat = true;
      liveAstrologerController.update();
      liveAstrologerController.chatId = chatId;
      int waitListId = int.parse(message.data["waitListId"].toString());
      String time = liveAstrologerController.waitList
          .where((element) => element.id == waitListId)
          .first
          .time;
      liveAstrologerController.endTime =
          DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch +
              1000 * int.parse(time.toString());
      liveAstrologerController.update();
    } else {
      if (liveAstrologerController.isOpenPersonalChatDialog) {
        Get.back(); //if chat dialog opended
        liveAstrologerController.isOpenPersonalChatDialog = false;
      }
      liveAstrologerController.isUserJoinAsChat = false;
      liveAstrologerController.chatId = null;
      liveAstrologerController.update();
    }
  } else if (message.notification!.title ==
      "For timer and session start for live") {
    int waitListId = int.parse(message.data["waitListId"].toString());
    liveAstrologerController.joinedUserName =
        message.data["name"] ?? "User";
    liveAstrologerController.joinedUserProfile =
        message.data["profile"] ?? "";
    String time = liveAstrologerController.waitList
        .where((element) => element.id == waitListId)
        .first
        .time;
    liveAstrologerController.endTime =
        DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch +
            1000 * int.parse(time.toString());
    liveAstrologerController.update();
  } else if (message.notification!.title == "Start simple chat timer") {
    chatController.newIsStartTimer = true;
    chatController.update();

    timerController.endTime =
        DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch + 1000 * 300;
    timerController.update();
  } else if (message.notification!.title == "End chat from customer") {
    log('isInChatScreen ${chatController.isInChatScreen}');

    if (chatController.isInChatScreen) {
      chatController.updateChatScreen(false);
      apiHelper.setAstrologerOnOffBusyline("Online");
      chatController.update();

      //  Get.back();
    } else {
      log('do nothing chat dismiss');
    }
  } else if (message.notification!.title ==
      "Reject call request from astrologer") {
    print('user Rejected call request:-');
    callController.isRejectCall = true;
    callController.update();
    callController.rejectDialog();
  } else {
    try {
      if (message.data.isNotEmpty) {
        var messageData = json.decode((message.data['body']));

        log('noti body $messageData');
        if (messageData['notificationType'] != null) {
          if (messageData['notificationType'] == 7) {
            // get wallet api call
            await walletController.getAmountList();
            NotificationHandler().foregroundNotification(message);
            await FirebaseMessaging.instance
                .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
                    alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
          } else if (messageData['notificationType'] == 8) {
            log('inside foreground noti type 8');
            chatController.startRingTone();
            chatController.chatList.clear();
            chatController.update();
            await chatController.getChatList(false);
            NotificationHandler().foregroundNotification(message);
            await FirebaseMessaging.instance
                .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
                    alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);

            //SHOW CHAT DIALOG
          } else if (messageData['notificationType'] == 2) {
            callController.startRingTone();

            log('iniside noti type 2');
            callController.callList.clear();
            callController.update();
            await callController.getCallList(false);
            NotificationHandler().foregroundNotification(message);
            await FirebaseMessaging.instance
                .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
                    alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
          } else if (messageData['notificationType'] == 9) {
            reportController.reportList.clear();
            reportController.update();
            await reportController.getReportList(false);
            NotificationHandler().foregroundNotification(message);
            await FirebaseMessaging.instance
                .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
                    alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
          } else if (messageData['notificationType'] == 12 ||
              messageData['notificationType'] == 11 ||
              messageData['notificationType'] == 10) {
            liveAstrologerController.isUserJoinWaitList = true;
            liveAstrologerController.update();
            NotificationHandler().foregroundNotification(message);
            await FirebaseMessaging.instance
                .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
                    alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
          } else {
            NotificationHandler().foregroundNotification(message);
            await FirebaseMessaging.instance
                .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
                    alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
          }

          NotificationHandler().foregroundNotification(message);
          await FirebaseMessaging.instance
              .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
                  alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
        } else {
          NotificationHandler().foregroundNotification(message);
          await FirebaseMessaging.instance
              .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
                  alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
        }
      } else {
        NotificationHandler().foregroundNotification(message);
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance
            .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
                alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      NotificationHandler().foregroundNotification(message);
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance
          .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
              alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
    }
  }
});
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  NotificationHandler().onSelectNotification(json.encode(message.data));
   });
 }
 SplashController splashController = Get.put(SplashController());
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return GetBuilder<SplashController>(builder: (s) {
       return Sizer(
         builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) => GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      navigatorKey: Get.key,
      enableLog: true,
      theme: Themes.light,
      darkTheme: Themes.dark,
      themeMode: ThemeService().theme,
      locale: context.locale,
      localizationsDelegates: [
        ...context.localizationDelegates,
        FallbackLocalizationDelegate()
      ],
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      initialBinding: NetworkBinding(),
      title: global.appName,
      initialRoute: "SplashScreen",
      home: SplashScreen(
        a: analytics,
        o: observer,
         ),
      
       ),
     );
   });
}

void inthandlerbackgroudn() async {
   FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
   FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundMessage);
   await messaging.requestPermission(
   alert: true,
   announcement: false,
   badge: true,
   carPlay: false,
   criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: false,
   );
 }
 }

and my NotificaitonHandler class is
 class NotificationHandler {
      final localNotifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
      WalletController walletController = Get.put(WalletController());
      ReportController reportController = Get.put(ReportController());
      HomeController homecontroller = Get.put(HomeController());
      SignupController signupController = Get.put(SignupController());
      ChatController chatController = Get.find<ChatController>();
      CallController callController = Get.find<CallController>();

Future<void> onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> messageData;
  try {
    messageData = json.decode(payload);
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> body;
  body = jsonDecode(messageData['body']);
  if (body["notificationType"] == 7) {
    await walletController.getAmountList();
    Get.to(() => WalletScreen());
  } else if (body["notificationType"] == 8) {
    chatController.stopRingtone();
    Get.find<HomeController>().homeTabIndex = 0;
    Get.find<HomeController>().update();
    Get.to(() => const HomeScreen());
  } else if (body["notificationType"] == 2) {
    callController.stopRingtone();
    debugPrint('list length ${callController.callList.length}');
    callController.callList
        .removeWhere((call) => call.callId == body['callId']);
    callController.update();
    if (body['call_type'].toString() == '10') {
      callController.acceptCallRequest(
          body['callId'],
          body['profile'],
          body['name'],
          body['id'],
          body['fcmToken'],
          body['call_duration']);
    } else if (body['call_type'].toString() == '11') {
      callController.acceptVideoCallRequest(
          body['callId'],
          body['profile'],
          body['name'],
          body['id'],
          body['fcmToken'],
          body['call_duration']);
    }
    Get.find<HomeController>().homeTabIndex = 2; //pageview index
    Get.find<HomeController>().isSelectedBottomIcon = 1; // bottom bar index
    Get.find<HomeController>().update();
  } else if (body["notificationType"] == 9) {
  } else if (body["notificationType"] == 13) {
    if (Get.find<HomeController>().notificationHandlingremoteUID != 0) {
      global.showToast(message: 'You are already live, end call first');
    } else {}
  }
} catch (e) {
  debugPrint(
    'Exception in onSelectNotification main.dart:- ${e.toString()}',
  );
}

}
  Future<void> foregroundNotification(RemoteMessage payload) async {
     final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
      defaultPresentBadge: true,
      requestSoundPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
     defaultPresentSound: true,
     onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) async {
        debugPrint("object notification call");
      return;
    },
  );
   AndroidInitializationSettings android =
    const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
final InitializationSettings initialSetting = InitializationSettings(
    android: android, iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin);
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initialSetting,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (_) {
  NotificationHandler().onSelectNotification(json.encode(payload.data));
});
AndroidNotificationChannel channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
  ' local notifications',
  'High Importance Notifications for ',
  importance: Importance.high,
);

AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
  channel.id,
  channel.name,
  importance: Importance.max,
  priority: Priority.high,
  icon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
  playSound: false,
  styleInformation: const BigTextStyleInformation(''),
);
const DarwinNotificationDetails iOSDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails();
NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
    NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iOSDetails);
global.sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
if (global.sp!.getString("currentUser") != null) {
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    0,
    payload.notification!.title,
    payload.notification!.body,
    platformChannelSpecifics,
    payload: json.encode(payload.data.toString()),
  );
}

}
}
i am getting two different hascode of chatcontroller instance in my app and onselected notification has
[log] chat hascode MyApp 445182886
[log] chat hascode bghandler 668612596
[log] chat hascode NotificationHandler 445182886

                            


First Approach  ok first thing is my approached is totally wrong i am using my own audioplayer to ring and to stop thats not good idea because firebase messaging handler is already an Isolate run saperately so the instance created inside it having diffrent refrences than created in myapp so the solution i found is direactly use inbuild feature of firebase messaging and fluttter_notification here what i did
First api Side you have to pass
[
'title' => 'Hey User you received a chat request from John Doe',
'body' => [
    'description' => 'Hey you received a chat request from User' . $user[0]->name,
    'notificationType' => 8,
    'icon' => 'public/notification-icon/chat.png',
],
'android' => [
    'notification' => [
        'channel_id' => 'channel_id_13',
        'sound' =>'app_sound' // don't use app_sound.mp3 or .wav only name
    ]
],
'apns' =>[
        'payload' => [
                    'aps' => [
                        'sound' => 'app_sound.wav'
                    ]
                ]
  ]
  ];

please note down you have to set sound and channel_id
 'android' => [
    'notification' => [
        'channel_id' => 'channel_id_13',
        'sound' =>'app_sound'. //for android only ringtone name 
    ]
],

and use both on you app side in android manifest and in code like i did below
 <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" 
        android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="channel_id_13"/>  

and inside you maniefest application tag remember adding same channel id
android:value="channel_id_13"

and now in our code we can create notification for support both background and foreground is
Future<void> foregroundNotificatioCustomAuddio(RemoteMessage payload) async {
final initializationSettingsDarwin = DarwinInitializationSettings(
  defaultPresentBadge: true,
  requestSoundPermission: true,
  requestBadgePermission: true,
  defaultPresentSound: false,
  onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) async {
    return;
  },
);
final android = const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
final initialSetting = InitializationSettings(
    android: android, iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin);

localNotifications.initialize(initialSetting,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (_) {
  onSelectNotification(json.encode(payload.data));
});

final customSound = 'app_sound.wav';
AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails =
    const AndroidNotificationDetails(
  'channel_id_13',  //same id here too
  'channel.name',
  importance: Importance.max,
  icon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
  playSound: true,
  enableVibration: true,
  timeoutAfter: 10000,
  sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('app_sound'),
);

DarwinNotificationDetails iOSDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails(
  sound: customSound,
);
final platformChannelSpecifics =
    NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iOSDetails);
global.sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

if (global.sp!.getString("currentUser") != null) {
  await localNotifications.show(
    10,
    payload.notification!.title,
    payload.notification!.body,
    platformChannelSpecifics,
    payload: json.encode(payload.data.toString()),
  );
  }
 }
final localNotifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

now calling from
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {

          NotificationHandler()
                .foregroundNotificatioCustomAuddio(message);
                await FirebaseMessaging.instance
                .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
                     alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);

          }

and for background now firebase handle the notification automatically now remember to add app_sound.wav formate ringtone in your android/app/src/main/res/raw/app_sound.wav thats it will work i have tested these in android 9 and android 10
The only problem i see in this that if you get first time notification in background then it will play normal default sound but if first notification you get is in foreground then it will work later fine on any condition searching for solution for this too if anybody have any idea related to this pls share
Second Approach so after lot of research i found that firebase didn't initialized notification sound before it didn't initialized in foreground so the workaround i found out is to create a method channel on app start and initialized it main.dart on app start
initstate of main.dart call this method
NotificationMethodChannel().createNewChannel();

and
class NotificationMethodChannel {
   void createNewChannel() async {
       const notichannel = 
        MethodChannel('com.org.myapp/channel_test');

Map<String, String> channelMap = {
  "id": "channel_id_18",
  "name": "Chats",
  "description": "Chat notifications",
};
log('create channel start');
try {
  final bool finished =
      await notichannel.invokeMethod('mynotichannel', channelMap);
  log('create channel start $finished');

  if (finished) {
    log('create channel finished successfully!');
  }
  log('create channel start finsihed $channelMap and status is $finished ');
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  log('create channel exception is $e');
}
}
}

after that go to android folder packagename and in mainActivity.kt file paste this code
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL_NAME = "com.org.myapp/channel_test"

       override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: 
 FlutterEngine) 
  {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
     MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, 
         CHANNEL_NAME).setMethodCallHandler {
      call, result ->
         Log.e("TAG", "channel name is ${call.method}")

  if (call.method == "mynotichannel"){
      Log.e("TAG", "argument start: ${call.arguments}")

    val argData = call.arguments as java.util.HashMap<String, 
   String>
      val completed = createNotificationChannel(argData)
      Log.e("TAG", "completed: $completed")
      if (completed == true){
          Log.e("TAG", "in true part")

          result.success(completed)
      }
      else{
          Log.e("TAG", "in false part")

          result.error("Error Code", "Error Message", null)
      }
  } else {
    result.notImplemented()
  }
}

}
private fun createNotificationChannel(mapData: HashMap<String,String>): Boolean {
    val completed: Boolean
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // Create the NotificationChannel
        val id = mapData["id"]
        val name = mapData["name"]
        val descriptionText = mapData["description"]
        val sound = "app_sound"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val mChannel = NotificationChannel(id, name, importance)
        mChannel.description = descriptionText

        val soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"+ applicationContext.packageName + "/raw/app_sound");
        val att = AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
        .build();

        mChannel.setSound(soundUri, att)
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
        completed = true
    }
    else{
        completed = false
    }
    return completed
}
}

Now it will work as expected remember to add MainActivity package path in androidManifest.xml and remove MainActivity.java if you are working on kotlin file
